# Progress bar update with the length of the list

Tags: python-3.x, progress-bar, tqdm

I am using tqdm for a progress bar. Here is the sample code

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

for index_len in tqdm(range(0,len(data_elim))):

    # Doing something here where i get a array of rows which i need to delete

      data_elim = np.delete(data_elim.values,same_residues,0                      
      data_elim = pd.DataFrame(data_elim)
```

So In this case, my initial length  is 17 mil, but as it goes further, this will decrease and eventually come to zero.  But In my progress bar, it always shows as initial length of the list.  Is there anyway I can change that number in the progress bar too ?

Comment: Have you used your code with a smaller dataset? if your total rows are 17M, 1% of the progress bar will change after 170K rows have been deleted (assuming the bar gets updated every 1%). Maybe not enough time has passed for this to happen?

Answer (score 2):

Without running the code, it feels like you could rewrite this to use the `tqdm` "manual" mode to be more explicit:

```
total_count = len(data_elim)
with tqdm(total=total_count) as progress:
  # ... do stuff, yielding `new_data`; or, calculate rows_deleted differently
  rows_deleted = total_count - len(new_data)
  progress.update(rows_deleted)
```